# form onsubmit won't work unless in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, onsubmit

I recently started doing form validation and I am trying to understand something. I have yet to find this anywhere else on SE.

When I have `onsubmit="return validateForm()"` or `onsubmit="validateForm()"` in the `<form>` element, the form does not do anything. However, when I remove `onsbumit` from the form tag and instead do `document.forms["favorite"].onsubmit = function validateForm()` in the JS file, it works fine.

I got it working, but I am trying to understand why the "normal" method of `onsubmit` in the html isn't working.

For reference, here is my code as it works now:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="form.js"></script>
    <title>Form</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form name="favorite" action="#" method="post">
      Favorite Car Brand: <input type="text" name="car">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
window.onload = function(){
  document.forms["favorite"].onsubmit = function validateForm(){
    var input = document.forms["favorite"]["car"].value;
    if(input == ""){
      alert("You missed an entry");
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, using `onsubmit` is certainly to be avoided, as it is mixing your presentation (HTML) with your logic (JavaScript). That said, `onsubmit="return validateForm()"` should work if you add `return true;` to the end of `validateForm()` so that it always returns a value.

Comment: This question is also quite similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/26192657/215552.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan alright, I tried that and it works, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all we define a function and then we call that function. and you are calling that function before defining as you are using window.load.You need to define the validation function before window.load as you are using. Sorry for my poor English.

```
<script>
    window.onload = function () {
        function validateForm() {
            var input = document.forms["favorite"]["car"].value;
            if (input == "") {
                alert("You missed an entry");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

define `validateForm()` function before window.load you do not need to write this function inside the window.load.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <title>Form</title>
        <script>
            function validateForm() {
                    var input = document.forms["favorite"]["car"].value;
                    if (input == "") {
                        alert("You missed an entry");
                        return false;
                    }
                }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="favorite" action="#" onsubmit="return validateForm();" method="post">
            Favorite Car Brand: <input type="text" name="car">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>


    </body>
</html>
```